# Activating SQL imported hyperlinks within Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-office

Morning All,

I have some SQL reports outputting to Excel templates & would like to mask a reference with a link to the related within a internal web based application.

Adding the hyperlink function manually works as expected but I would like to construct the link automatically as part of the report output.

I've got the function being compiled within the excel document but the link isn't 'active' just shown as plain text which from what I have read is a limitation on Excels part, is there anyway to add some VBA to the worksheet or workbook which will activate/re-format these links when the document is opened (simulate F2 & Enter)? via VBA? (I have limited knowledge of VBA & Excel)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

[image: OrigReportFormatting]

Comment: Are you using SSRS ?

Comment: No, straight from a sproc using openrowset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
For Each r in desiredRange
    r.Formula = r.Text
Next
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much avb, combined with Auto_Open this does exactly what I was after.